# Invalid variant type error Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, variant

```
// interface

    iccItem =
        class
            ID   : String;
            DATA : Variant;
            constructor Create( _id : String; _data : Variant);
        end;

    iccDynamicObject =
        class
             private
                 FItems : TList;
                 function locate( _id : String) : iccItem;
             public
                 constructor Create();
                 destructor Destroy(); override;
             public
                 procedure define( _id : String; _dta : Variant);
                 //function get( _ndx : DWORD)  : Variant; overload;// link to original data
                 function get( _id  : String) : Variant; overload;
             public
                 property Items[_id : String] : Variant read get write define; default;
        end;


// implementation

{ iccDynamicObject }

constructor iccItem.Create( _id : String; _data : Variant);
begin
    ID   := _id;
    DATA := _data;
end;

function iccDynamicObject.locate( _id : String) : iccItem;
var ndx : integer;
    tmp : iccItem;
begin
    result := nil;

    for ndx := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do
        begin
            tmp := iccItem( FItems[ndx]);
            if tmp.ID = _id
                then begin
                         result := tmp;
                         exit;
                     end;
        end;
end;

constructor iccDynamicObject.Create();
begin
    FItems := TList.Create();
end;

destructor iccDynamicObject.Destroy();
begin
    {$MESSAGE 'clear here'}

    FItems.Destroy();
    inherited;
end;

procedure iccDynamicObject.define( _id : String; _dta : Variant);
var tmp : iccItem;
begin
    tmp := locate( _id);
    if tmp = nil
        then FItems.Add( iccItem.Create( _id, _dta) )
        else tmp.DATA := _dta;
end;

//function iccDynamicObject.get( _ndx : DWORD) : Variant;
//begin
//    result.vPointer := nil;
//end;

function iccDynamicObject.get( _id : String) : Variant;
var tmp : iccItem;
begin
    tmp := locate( _id);
    if tmp = nil
        then result.vaNull := true
        else result := locate( _id).DATA;
end;


// using
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var c : iccDynamicObject;
begin
    c := iccDynamicObject.Create;

    c['asd'] := 123;

    c.Destroy;
end;
```

Set breakpoint in DELPHI 2010 at   iccDynamicObject.define() ->     tmp := locate( _id); 
will cause @**Project Project1.exe raised exception class EVariantBadVarTypeError with message 'Invalid variant type'.**@

Code was tested in DELPHI 7, and this problem was not encountered!

ps. code was rewritten in delphi-7 style without in-class types for demonstrating a problem...

**SOLVED -> Do not use in-class generic types**, such as

```
classDef<_type> = 
    class
        type
            // this
            internalClass<_anotherType> =
                class
                    private
                        FSomething : _anotherType;
                end;
            // or this one
            internalClass2 =
                class
                    private
                        FSomething : _type;
                end;
        private
            FInternalClass  : internalClass<_type>;
            FInternalClass2 : internalClass;
    end;
```

Such things will procure debugger or compiler to do UNEXCECTED THINGS!!!
Code compiles and work correctly. But in my case, with Unit growth code become unstable
and coerce me to make some code-refactoring, just a little, but more than inconvenient...

You are Noticed :)))

Comment: If the problem was really that you had a class nested in a generic class, then could you please edit the question so that the code exhibits the problem you say it does? *Of course* the code works in Delphi 7; that version doesn't even support generics.

Comment: @that version doesn't even support generics@ - wow, you're genious!!! WOW!!! as you could not understand, i wrote that problems were encountered BY GENERICS that are present in delphi2010. please, read carefully next time, ok?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug in D2010 which has been [reported in QualityCentral](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=84930) and fixed in XE.

Comment: I so dislike that: you buy D2010, it has a bug but it's only fixed in the next version that you do NOT get for free.

Comment: @Remko @Dorin I dislike this too and it is frustrating. But I don't agree that they don't give a damn about their customers. I think they are poor at communicating with them at times, but they are getting better. It's hard for EMB to patch bugs in older and older versions of the SW. In this particular case it is very easy to work around.

Comment: @David: well I do know that my customers would not accept it no matter the reason... I wouldn't go so far as saying that EMB doesn't care at all but I would consider it reasonable to fix bugs in the latest-1 or latest-2 version. IMO they should on forehand make a support statement that clearly indicates to which point in time they will fix bugs in a particular version.

Comment: @Remko: I'm going to play devil's advocate. If they were to fix all the bugs in say, version latest-1 or latest-2 that would involve a very significant engineering effort. Lots of development and testing. Personally, much as I'd like bugs in 2010 fixed, if I can work around them in a reasonable way I'd much rather they concentrated on improving the main line product (64 bit is the thing I want to see). If back-porting fixes took effort away from 64 bit then I would not want it to be done.

Comment: @Remko: What would be much better though would be for the overall quality of the product to be higher (as it was in D7, say). That way the back-porting would be easier. I doubt they could fix this particular bug without a huge effort (that they already did in XE).

Comment: @David well I must say that I think the overall quality of D2010 is satisfying for me but I think it's bad idea that's it not clearly defined which bugs will be fixed in a particular version and which not. It's all up to EMB's discrection!

Comment: @David it's all about making profit, they knew about the errors YET they released the version in order to sell licenses and then FIX or UNCOMMENT fixes in the source to release a new version which results in selling more licenses and make more profit, now I don't want you to think that I'm paranoid about this but that's the way they work, they felt it's not enough just to give a few patches so they included third party products -- please tell me that it's NOT about profit or that they CARE about customers... I sooo want to believe it's so...

Comment: @Dorin: Everyone releases software knowing it contains bugs. In fact it is better for everyone (vendor and customer) that this is the case. If you spend ages fixes all the inconsequential bugs then you deprive your customers of the major improvements you have made. Emb certainly do not release low quality code so that they can just fix it later and charge for an upgrade.

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: Delphi (and usually other software too) has so many outstanding feature-requests, that they don't need to make deliberate errors or uncomment fixes to justify a new version. Every software company releases products with known errors, otherwise there will never be a release.

Comment: @The_Fox: I "just" realized that we're sooo out of topic :-P but still I always love debates because you mostly learn something new. I would love to see the code of Delphi compiler and/or IDE so I can prove I'm right or to see that I'm wrong about this, but unfortunately it's impossible at this time, however there is always a possibility o code "leak", as they "leak" cracked versions so that people can play with it without actually buying...

Comment: @The Bug-Fixes as Upgrade Incentive Crowd:  That is all well and good, but let's say you are using Delphi 2006 and there is some bug in that product that is not fixed in 2007 or 2009.  Let us further say that in addition to not fixing bugs, the new versions introduce NEW bugs or changes in behaviour which adversely affect your code.  So you don't upgrade - it would be a waste of money.  Then Embarcadero say:  If you don't upgrade to Delphi 2010, then you lose the right to upgrade to any later versions.  THAT is the point at which it becomes unacceptable, and we reached that point last year.

Comment: @Deltics: This is harse. XE is practically nothing but bug fixes.

Comment: @David Heffernan: "nothing BUT bug fixes" YET they sell it as a NEW PRODUCT -- how does this look to you, like they give a damn about their customers?! NO, the only thing they are interested in is to gain more customers, but how can you support more customers if your current customers ARE NOT EVEN HALF HAPPY with the service and products you provide?

Comment: @Dorin: Would you prefer they didn't fix the bugs? Or would you prefer they gave it away and went out of business leaving you (and the rest of us) with great code/products but no compiler? As I understand it Emba are working on X-platform and x64 which will take some time to brew and so on an annual release schedule there will inevitable be a release with little meat in.

Comment: @David: How about they admit/accept that XE is primarily bug fixes, not to mention, failing completely to deliver on what was intended for the release, and offer it to existing customers as a paid-for upgrade, but at a LOWER price than a normal upgrade?  And how about NOT applying the rolling "2 versions to qualify for Upgrade rights" policy to this release?  It's not a question of "FREE or STUPIDLY EXPENSIVE"... there is middle ground, if Embarcadero were willing to show a little good will.  They clearly aren't.  Their view of their customers is clear.  We are cash cows to be milked.  Moo.

Comment: @Deltics @Dorin I don't think they are evil and malicious, just very bad at communicating. I must admit I felt they shoot themselves in the foot in the XE announcement which was essentially vacuous. They are incapable of giving meaningful forward looking statements. However, some of that may be related to the trading rules that apply to EMBA which is listed I believe.

Comment: Can you please provide the QC number?

Comment: @David - Borland were listed and management invoked SOX as a smokescreen to excuse their poor communication.  It was never a reason, only an excuse.  But Embarcadero are privately held, not listed - SOX does not apply.  They are poor at communicating because, well, they are poor at communicating.  And you completely ignored the question of why they could not have released XE as an interim, paid for upgrade at less than full-upgrade pricing.  That is not a question of poor communication, regulatory requirements or anything else.  It's just a reflection of their attitude towards their customers.

Comment: (but this is waaay off-topic - feel free to email me direct if you wish to discuss further)

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning `tmp := nil;` in the locate method next to where you assign nil to result.  If this resolves the exception, I'll explain why.

Comment: debugger can not even get to this method!!! if breakpoint is not set, code is working correctly WITHOUT any error.

Comment: You kind of failed to mention this (that setting the breakpoint causes the exception) in your original description.

Comment: @Set breakpoint in DELPHI 2010 at iccDynamicObject.define() -> tmp := locate( _id); will cause@ read again

Answer (score 1):

This problem occured by unexpected debugger or compiler behavior, and such behavior was caused by bugs in Delphi 2010 (they might be fixed in Delphi XE, as `David Heffernan` mentioned).

I have only one conclusion: **Do not use in-class generic types**, such as:

```
classDef<_type> = 
    class
        type
            // this
            internalClass<_anotherType> =
                class
                    private
                        FSomething : _anotherType;
                end;
            // or this one
            internalClass2 =
                class
                    private
                        FSomething : _type;
                end;
        private
            FInternalClass  : internalClass<_type>;
            FInternalClass2 : internalClass;
    end;
```

Such things will cause the debugger or compiler to do unexpected things. The code compiles and works correctly. But in my case, with Unit growth code becoming unstable it has forced me to do some code-refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a New VCL Forms Applications, including the code you provided?
I did...

1- setting the break point does not do anything (no harm either), because you have to read your item to call get(_id)
2- I added a line to that effect:

```
c['asd'] := 123;
i := c['asd'];   // <=== added
c.Destroy;
```

3- the breakpoint worked as expected, without any exception

So I'm guessing there is something else going on....

Comment: I guess, I've found a problem. Generics... sh*t DElphi's generics in the same Unit causes debugger to do something VERY strange :(

Comment: yeap, problem was caused by buggy delphi's generics ( :( ). Do not use in-class generic types. declare them outside the `main` class

Comment: @Focker. Then I suggest you build a small (self sufficient) example that actually do show the problem and submit in QC. Only way bugs get to be fixed...

Comment: as you can see, thread was updated 1 hour ago... example included. what you SHOULD NOT DO in Delphi 2010.