# How to bypass Invalid variant type in c++ builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I try to create non visual component in c++ builder, and that work fine without error, than try to create visual component and everything work until last step when those component run in application. When I try to run it from application always get: **Invalid variant type.**

What's that mean? What should I do to bypass that? Do you have some good link for tutorial where can see how to make component and import it? I search lot of on google but didn't find satisfactorily solution.

Comment: I can upload full project but it would help as much the problem is not in the code (it show simple messagebox from button)

Comment: You need to use the debugger, or an exception handling library like MadExcept or EurekaLog, to catch the exception when it occurs and show you exactly where it is being raised from, what the call stack looks like, etc.  Without that kind of information, you are not going to be able to track this problem down.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey Remy I upload video of how I create custom component and whre Invalid variant type occur [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIg91GiO0G4&feature=plcp)

Comment: Again, please learn how to use the debugger. You have a DLL project and a EXE project. Set the EXE as the Host for the DLL, then run the DLL project inside the IDE. The EXE will run. When it loads the DLL into memory, you will be able to put breakpoints inside your DLL code, such as in the `OnClick` event handler, and find out exactly where your Variant error is coming from. I can tell you right now that `ShowMessage()` is not an ActiveX-compatible funtion. Use Microsoft's Win32 API `MessageBox()` function instead.

Comment: No ... I install Eurake and madexecept as Remy say but that have some other problems. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361853/invalid-variant-type-error-delphi-2010) may help you. I think that XE still have bug with   generic classes.